# Incoming packets version handling - design issues

Tags: c++

Consider packet coming from somewhere. It has field VERSION, there are N possible VERSIONS of incoming packet.
Every packet with VERSION X has to be processed by proper methods/set of instructions for every packet VERSION from X to 1. My only idea to accomplish this task is very ugly like:

```
PACKET p = GetPacketFromSomewhere();
// p.VERSION is 3

if (p.VERSION > 0) {
  // things for p.VERSION == 1
}

if (p.VERSION > 1) {
  // things for p.VERSION == 2
}

if (p.VERSION > 2) {
  // things for p.VERSION == 3
}

// set of if statements up to version N
```

The real situation is that, I have packet VERSIONS above number 10 and things still are likely to change. New packet VERSIONS will be added while I need to keep backward compatibility. This code is bad, at least I don't like it. Do you guys have any better idea how to handle this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `map` of type `map<unsigned int, function>` where `function` is a pointer to a function of the desired type:

```
typedef void (*function)();
std::map<int,function> handlers;
handlers[1] = &ver1handler;
...
handlers[N] = &verNhandler;

if(handlers.count(p.VERSION))
   (*handlers.find(p.VERSION))();
```

where `ver[N+1]handler` would be defined as:

```
void ver[N+1]handler(){
   ver[N]handler();
   // additional handle commands
}
```

Or use the `switch` command, with the handlers defined in the same way.

Comment: Your solution would be appropriate if OP wanted to execute a single block for any given version number. It sounds like s/he wants to execute every block *up to* the given number; e.g. for `VERSION==3`, it should execute blocks 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice. Changed the post :)

Comment: I don't think there is a need for std:map here. A simple vector - with the protocol version beeing the index of the functions - should be sufficient.

Comment: Only if all the versions exist. I don't know what the OP is trying to implement, but that's not always the case (like in the IP protocol).

Comment: It's still not optimal solution because while adding handling for new VERSION I had to add: new handler function, add handler function to map. I know it seems trivial but what if I forget adding new handler function to map? Nevertheless thank you so much for your idea, we'll see if someone come out with another solution.

Comment: @igleyy - if you forget to add the handler to the map, nothing will happen. No error, no crash, the packet simply won't be handled. It depends on what you mean by "optimal", this version should work faster for larger version numbers (logarythmic in packet version), and I doubt you could find a faster solution. If you're really worried about forgetting to add a handler, do a class which adds the hander to the map, inside its constructor (that would be an overkill IMHO, but it's your choice here).

Answer (score 2):

If the order of processing is not important, you can use switch without break:

```
PACKET p = GetPacketFromSomewhere();
// p.VERSION is 3

switch (p.VERSION) {
    case 3: {
        // things for p.VERSION == 3
    }
    case 2: {
        // things for p.VERSION == 2
    }
    case 1: {
        // things for p.VERSION == 1
    }
}
```

EDIT:
You could also use recursive function template specialization like this:

```
template<int N>
void proc(PACKET& p){
    proc<N-1>(p);        
}

template<>
void proc<1>(PACKET& p){
     //things for p.VERSION == 1
}

template<>
void proc<2>(PACKET& p){
    proc<1>(p)
    //things for p.VERSION == 2
}

template<>
void proc<3>(PACKET& p){
    proc<2>(p)
    //things for p.VERSION == 3
}
```

and then call the processing function like this:

```
switch (p.VERSION ) {
    case 1: proc<1>(p) break;
    case 3: proc<2>(p) break;
    case 3: proc<3>(p) break;
    default: {
        std::cout << "Protocol version not impplemented - using highest known version" << std::endl;
        proc<3>(p); 
}
```

This should also be pretty efficient performance wise (in case this is a concern of yours) and you don't have to worry about gaps in the protocol version.

Comment: I guess that compiler orders cases by himself and I see only case 1: executed. There is my test code http://pastebin.com/iDBVPkvh

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I corrected the condition in the switch statement.

Comment: Regarding your earlier question: I'd simply stick to your original solution, if you have to use the procesing functions in ascending order. If you need to interleave funtions from higher protocol versions between lower ones, you should use a recursive definition.